# want to create a link to move to specified div on the samepage in mvc

Tags: c#, html, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am creating a site with C# .net MVC 3 i want to link a menu option which on click should go to specified div...The id of div is "portfolio" which is in index.cshtml and the menu option which has to be linked is in layout.cshtml...
gone through various documentations but didn't found solution...i have tried the native html method but is not working.

```
<li class="page-scroll">
                    <a href="#portfolio">Inspiration</a>
                </li>
```

Comment: it should work and has nothing to do with MVC... are you sure the id you're targetting is the same ? (check for upper/lower case...). Is it in the same window ? (no frame, iFrame, ...)

Comment: As @Bartdude said "has nothing to do with MVC". Can you provide the complete html? or at least the target div.

Answer (score 0):

just simple dude  use this  :-

"toggle visibility to use it for different tabs"

```
<style type="text/css">
.section {
    display: none;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">

function toggleVisibility(newSection) {
    $(".section").not("#" + newSection).hide();
    $("#" + newSection).show();
}
</script>
```

use this in navigation field:-

```
<a href="#" onclick="toggleVisibility('portfolio');">portfolio</a>
```

use this as portfolio div:-

```
<div id="portfolio" class="section">
//body
  </div>
```

Comment: This is based on html and jquery..!

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
$('a').on('click', function () {
    $('html, body').animate({           
        scrollTop: $('#portfolio').offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

That will give you a nice scroll effect.

Answer (score 0):

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<ul>
    <li class="page-scroll">
        <a href="#portfolio">Inspiration</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
<div style="height:150px;background-color:Yellow">
    //Content for this block goes here
</div>

<div id="portfolio" style="height:50px;">
   //Here you want to move
</div>

<div style="height:150px;background-color:Gray">
    //Content for this block goes here
</div>
```

It works on every view if the div block with that id included in each view.